# ElementTree insert element from another file and save

Tags: python, xml, block, elementtree, addchild

File1.xml

```
   <!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
    <qgis projectname="" version="2.6.1-Brighton">
        <title></title>
         <mapcanvas>

        </mapcanvas>
      </qgis>
```

File2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<legend updateDrawingOrder="true">
    <legendlayer checked="Qt::Checked" name="Grid1.shp" open="true" showFeatureCount="0">
        <filegroup hidden="false" open="true">
            <legendlayerfile isInOverview="0" layerid="Grid1_shp20150117231830763" visible="1"/>
        </filegroup>
    </legendlayer>
    <legendlayer checked="Qt::Checked" name="world_countries.shp" open="true" showFeatureCount="0">
        <filegroup hidden="false" open="true">
            <legendlayerfile isInOverview="0" layerid="world_countries_shp20150117231830790" visible="1"/>
        </filegroup>
    </legendlayer>
</legend>
```

I need to a section of File1.XML to File2.XML...Below script printing the desired but only for element.How can this update be saved in File2.XML?

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et

tree1 = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('File1.xml')
root1 = tree1.getroot()

tree2 = xml.etree.ElementTree.parse('File2.xml')
root2 = tree2.getroot()

root2.insert(0,root1)
print et.tostring(root2)
```

The target software expects the tags in below format

```
<!DOCTYPE qgis PUBLIC 'http://mrcc.com/qgis.dtd' 'SYSTEM'>
    <qgis projectname="" version="2.6.1-Brighton">
        <title></title>
<legend updateDrawingOrder="true">
    <legendlayer checked="Qt::Checked" name="Grid1.shp" open="true" showFeatureCount="0">
        <filegroup hidden="false" open="true">
            <legendlayerfile isInOverview="0" layerid="Grid1_shp20150117231830763" visible="1"/>
        </filegroup>
    </legendlayer>
    <legendlayer checked="Qt::Checked" name="world_countries.shp" open="true" showFeatureCount="0">
        <filegroup hidden="false" open="true">
            <legendlayerfile isInOverview="0" layerid="world_countries_shp20150117231830790" visible="1"/>
        </filegroup>
    </legendlayer>
</legend>

         <mapcanvas>

        </mapcanvas>
      </qgis>
```

Comment: Give short example input and desired output.

Comment: I have edited to provide example

Answer (score 0):

However you have built and/or modified your element tree, you can save it to disk with its `write` method:

```
tree2.write('File2.xml')
```

Comment: For the given example,  <title></title> is getting changed to <title/>

Comment: @ddurgaprasad, that's perfectly equivalent XML and entirely correct.  I don't think you can stop such XML **normalizations** (nor do I know of any reason you would **want** to).